# Two function names after func keyword - what is it?

Tags: go

How to understand the last function? 
Why do we use different function names after `func` declaration?
How to use those function? Using it like shown in the `main` function is wrong.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(incrementer()) //error
}

func incrementer() func() int { //what is it?!
    i := 0
    return func() int {
        i++
        return i
    }
}
```

Comment: It's covered in the tour. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, since `incrementer()` returns a function, the function that it returns must be called as well. You can do so like this:

```
functionFoo := incrementer()
fmt.Println(functionFoo())
```

Or this shorthanded way:

```
fmt.Println(incrementer()())
```

Which achieves the same thing, you just immediately execute the function that `incrementer()` returns.

Answer (score 6):

It just means that the function is returning a function that takes no parameters and returns an integer. That is what the

```
... func() int
```

part of your signature is saying.

The error you are getting is because you fmt.Println cannot print a function. To show this you can see that you get the same error if you call,

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(foo)
}

func foo() int {
  return 1
}
```

It might be clearer to see what is going on if you call your function like this.

```
func main() {
    myIncrementer := incrementer()
    fmt.Println(myIncrementer()) // Prints 1
}
```

Where you are creating incrementer, which is a function, then calling that function function which returns 1.